# Making a setup.py file ModuleNotFoundError when runing package

Tags: python, setup.py

I am trying to package a project for the first time and I am running into the issue where my 'linux.py' module is not being installed when I run pip. This is the error I get after installing when running my package.

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'linux'
```

linux.py is being included inside venus.py as such:

```
import linux
```

Here is my setup.py file

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
name='venus',
version='0.0.1',
description="A cross platform tool for setting a random wallpaper image from unsplash.com",
license="MIT",
#packages=['venus',],
packages=find_packages(),
install_requires=[
'requests',
],
entry_points={"console_scripts": ["venus = venus.venus:main"]},
)
```

Here is what the output from pip install . using virtualenv

```
Processing /home/user/Documents/venus
Requirement already satisfied: requests in ./env/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from venus==0.0.1) (2.19.1)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 in ./env/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from requests->venus==0.0.1) (3.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<2.8,>=2.5 in ./env/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from requests->venus==0.0.1) (2.7)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.24,>=1.21.1 in ./env/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from requests->venus==0.0.1) (1.23)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in ./env/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from requests->venus==0.0.1) (2018.10.15)
Building wheels for collected packages: venus
Running setup.py bdist_wheel for venus ... done
Stored in directory: /tmp/pip-ephem-wheel-cache-krjpkz8c/wheels/0e/fc/f8/94d809f34270dfc8e6944773a2a7f25f69f02eb580f2674ca6
Successfully built venus
Installing collected packages: venus
Successfully installed venus-0.0.1
```

And this is what my file structure looks like

```
venus
├── __init__.py
├── linux.py
└── venus.py
```

I have looked search for answers many times and have not found a  solution. As you can see in the setup.py file, I tried using the find_packages() function as well and that didn't solve it. What am I missing here?

I am using python 3.7
pip version 18.0

Comment: can try "from . import linux" instead of "import linux"

Comment: @ChristianSloper I tried it, but it did not work, I got a similar error. ImportError: cannot import name 'linux' from 'venus' (/home/user/Documents/venus/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/venus/__init__.py)

Comment: @ChristianSloper Actually that did it! I forgot I had changed the file name of linux.py. Why does this work?

Comment: @ChristianSloper I might have spoke too soon as it breaks the program when calling it from the terminal with python venus.py -> ImportError: cannot import name 'linux' from '__main__' (venus.py)

Comment: maybe you can upload to github and I can look at your solution there?  Its a bit hard to debug through comments alone :-)

Comment: `linux.py` is inside the `venus` package (a dir containing an `__init__.py`), so its name is `venus.linux`. Either do `from venus import linux` or `import venus.linux`.